# How to show default null value button in angular using *ngIf condition for like, dislike and default buttons inside *ngFor loop using Mysql Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Hi i am trying to make like, dislike and default buttons system like YouTube , But i got error when i was working with default button first two conditions(like, dislike) are working good but i am unable to show the default Button when there is no  value  in the MySQL table.Here i am using two table posts(post_id, user_id, description), likes(like_id, user_id, post_id, like_status) columns values.

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">

      <div class="
      row" style="border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0" style=" height: auto; ">
          <h6> {{post.description}} </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="row">

          <!--like button-->
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div *ngFor="let like of postLikes; let j = index ">

              <div
                *ngIf="( (postLikes != '') && (like.like_id != null) && (like.like_id != '') && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'like'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)><i
                    class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>{{like.user_id}},{{like.post_id}}
                {{post.post_id}} {{like.like_id}}
              </div>
              <div
                *ngIf="( (like.like_id) && (like.like_id != null) && (like.like_id != '') && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)><i
                    class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>{{like.user_id}},{{like.post_id}}
                {{post.post_id}} {{like.like_id}}
              </div>

              <div
                *ngIf=" (post.user_id !=like.user_id) && (!like.like_id) && (postLikes == '') && (like.like_id == null) && (like.like_id == '')">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-basic" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)><i
                    class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>{{like.user_id}},{{like.post_id}}
                {{post.post_id}} {{like.like_id}}
              </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you move logic to Component source code?
Should create a variable in component, it is easy to debug in component file.

```
( (postLikes != '') && (like.like_id != null) && (like.like_id != '') 
&& (post.user_id == like.user_id) 
&& (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'like'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i don't know how to do it , can you help me in this